# removing similar successive records in a sqlite3 table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I 've a big table in SQLite3 which is related to stock prices (as you can see in sample records). there are some similar successive records that just DateTime 's amount is different(Ask & Bid records are the same). I 'm searching for a way to remove these similar records(just keeping one of them). for example in this sample after removing, just 3 records will remain.
do you have any idea for a SQL code?
Thanks

[image: sample records]

**EDITED**:Table structure is obvious: CREATE TABLE table_name (DateTime TEXT, Bid REAL, Ask REAL);

Data is provided by Truefx.com in CSV formmat.

as described, desired output can vary. for example (in uploaded sample) one of first three rows must remain.final answer should be something like this:

DateTime -- Bid -- Ask

20170102 00:00:00.803 -- 1.0523 -- 1.05307

20170102 00:00:06.833 -- 1.05158 -- 1.05349

20170102 00:00:16.208 -- 1.0523 -- 1.05307

Comment: Please provide your table structure as a few lines of "create table ...", provide sample content as "insert ...", show your own coding attempts, show desired output. Do not link pictures of text.

Comment: Bascially, please make a [mcve]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If the dates wont matter, you can group by your bid and ask columns and use a aggregation funtion on the dates:

```
select bid,ask,max(date)
from table_name
group by bid,ask
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, look at my sample response. your code has an objection. It removes first row in sample response because it 's 'ask' and 'bid' amount is similar to the third record.

Comment: That's true but your question was in turn not precise enough. It gave the impression that you don't want to have these "duplicates" where only the timestamp changes and the respective bid/ask was the same. I would assume this data is meant to produce some HLOC (hogh-low-open-close) charts for a security/instrument or similar? You can also include your timestamp in the group by or use a select distinct only.

Comment: I edited the question.  yes, It 's Bid/Ask price for a security. I tested 'select distinct' and also included 'DateTime' to the 'group by'(two separate test) but they do not conclude the sample response.

Comment: Still your example seems incomplete to me. How do you define similarity then? Is there some other data/columns which you can use/show? Maybe you search for "how to emulate rank in sqlite in here" - maybe this helps then.